# Mailing the UK Visa application

Tags: visas, uk, applications, mail

I am confused at what the right mailing address is for UK visa application. My packet contains all the supporting documents.Is this the correct address?

> UK Visas and Immigration
>
> British consulate General  845 Third Avenue
>
> New York 10022

Comment: Where are you based? Are you a US Citizen?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can see you should be mailing to a different address:

> You should mail your application to:
>   VFS Services USA Inc.
>   UKVI Scanning Hub
>   145 West 45th St  Floor 5
>   New York NY  10036

According to the [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa)

Comment: This address has changed once in recent memory. It's a good idea to check it each time to ensure that it has not changed again.